# Mounting Entire Container into a Directory

Tags: debian, docker, backup, migration, volume

I am trying to mount my entire docker debian container into /home/admin/main directory of my vps as a backup and migration solution but I get an error.

*Command Used*

```bash
sudo docker run -ditv /home/admin/main:/ debian /bin/bash
```

*Error Received*

```bash
docker: Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: '/home/admin/main:/': invalid mount config for type "bind": invalid specification: destination can't be '/'.  See 'docker run --help'.
```

Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: not quite sure what you want to achieve with this? I find it quite logical that a container can't have its root directory be an external volume! What's the motivation behind doing this?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am newbie. I am not sure what to backup so I am trying to backup from root. So I will not miss if anything goes wrong. Can you guide be how should I backup my container using volumes in the best way. So that in case if I want to migrate to a new VPS I just can migrate the volumes and start again without missing anything.

Comment: `docker save` does that

Comment: To be clear, `docker save` creates a tarball containing the layers in a container image; if the goal here is to create a backup of volumes, it won’t help.